# Where does an interrupt vector table get stored in Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

After registering the ISR handler to kernel using **`request_irq`** is it possible to change the interrupt line to point to some other function/ISR by modifying IVT ?

`EDIT: X86 architecture`

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on several conditions, such as architecture, real or protected memory mode.
As far as I know, on x86 architecture, in protected mode there is IDT - Interrupt Descriptor Table where the pointers to Interrupt Service Routines (ISR) are located. 
And the address of IDT is stored in IDTR (Interrup Descriptor Table Register).